# Do I need to dispose both the CRM OrganizationServiceProxy and the OrganizationServiceContext?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Both the OrganizationServiceProxy and the OrganizationServiceContext support the dispose method.  Do I need to wrap both of them in a using statement?

```
using (var proxy = GetOrganizationServiceProxy(Constants.OrgName))
{
    using (var context = new OrganizationServiceContext(proxy))
    {
        // Linq Code Here
    }
 }
```

Or will disposing of the context close properly close the proxy, meaning only this is needed?

```
 var proxy = GetOrganizationServiceProxy(Constants.OrgName)
 using (var context = new OrganizationServiceContext(proxy))
 {
     // Linq Code Here
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The context cannot dispose the proxy, as it cannot decide if it is used by any other object.
IF you look into `Dispose` of OrganizationServiceContext, you'll see

```
public void Dispose()
{
  this.Dispose(true);
  GC.SuppressFinalize((object) this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (!disposing)
    return;
  this.ClearChanges();
}
```

btw. you can combine both using statements

```
using (var proxy = GetOrganizationServiceProxy(Constants.OrgName))
using (var context = new OrganizationServiceContext(proxy))
{
    // Linq Code Here
}
```

Comment: I like the double using statement.  That's a good idea.  Guess I could create a "context Manager" that handles both if I really wanted one using statement.  Thanks!

Comment: @Daryl sure you could create some manager class. However, if you add both usings it is clear which dependencies are required for this task